# Cannot find control with path in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, forms, typescript, angular4-forms

I am using angular 6 application and using dynamic forms.

app.component.html:

```
   <form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" [formGroup]="form">
    <div formArrayName="multiDynamic">
      <!-- row -->
      <div *ngFor="let record of form.controls.multiDynamic.controls; let i=index">
            <div class="row" [formGroupName]="i">
                <div class="col-md-6" *ngFor="let question of model.questions">
                    <div [ngSwitch]="question.controlType">
                        <div class="form-group form-black label-floating">
                            <label class="control-label">{{question.text | titlecase}} </label>
                            <div *ngSwitchCase="'textbox'"><input type="text" class="form-control" [formControlName]="question.key"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    <button type="submit> Submit </button>
  </form>
```

app.component.ts:
    import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
    import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators, FormControl, FormArray } from '@angular/forms';

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
 @Input() model: any;
form: FormGroup;

ngOnInit() {

this.sharedService.getData().subscribe(data => {
  this.items = data;
  console.log(this.items);
});

this.form = this.fb.group({
        multiDynamic: this.fb.array([
          this.model.toGroup()
        ])
      });
  }

}
```

console.log(model.questions) gives the following (expanded array),

```
0:Textbox {controlType: "textbox", key: "url-links", text: "url-links"}
1:Textbox {controlType: "textbox", key: "//input[@id='rcmloginuser']", text: "//input[@id='rcmloginuser']"}
2:Textbox {controlType: "textbox", key: "//input[@id='rcmloginpwd']", text: "//input[@id='rcmloginpwd']"}
3:Textbox {controlType: "textbox", key: "//input[@id='rcmloginsubmit'] ", text: "//input[@id='rcmloginsubmit'] "}
```

I am using the above html and ts files and if i give this line,

```
<input id="i" type="text" class="form-control" [formControlName]="question.text">
```

i am getting error as, 
**Cannot find control with path: 'multiDynamic -> 0 -> url-links'**

In label,

```
<label class="control-label"> {{question.text | titlecase}} </label>
```

the text value is getting displayed but if i give formControlName in input box, then i am getting this error.

I am using angular's dynamic form.

`this.model.toGroup()` is having the following,

```
export class DynamicFormMultiModel {
    questions = [];
multiDataResponse: any = [];
form: FormGroup;

toGroup() {
    const group: any = {};
    this.questions.forEach((question) => {
        group[question.key] = new FormControl('');
    });

    return new FormGroup(group);
}

    patchData() {
        const arrayGroup: any = {};
        const dataRes: any = [];
        const resObj: any = {};

        // this.multiDataResponse.forEach((element, index) => {
        //     this.questions.forEach((question, inx) => {
        //             arrayGroup[question.key] = new FormControl(element[question.key]);
        //     });
        // });
        resObj['data'] = this.multiDataResponse;

    // return new FormGroup(arrayGroup);
    return resObj;
    }
}
```

As i am having nested codes i am unable to post the entire code but i am getting data and its displaying in label but the input tag is throwing error. (Both contains same value `question.text`).

Attached the screenshot of the scenario.

[image]

Kindly help me to fix this stucked for too long time in it..

Comment: are you getting data from database and setting to form?

Comment: @Chellappan, Yes i am doing it.. You could able to see that i am getting same data in label but inside input box i couldn't..

Comment: Can you also post what you're doing in this method `this.model.toGroup()`?

Comment: @yurzui, Posted in the question.. Starting with ```export class DynamicFormMultiModel``` has that function..

Comment: How do you fill `this.model`?

Comment: Looks like you need to have question with key `url-link` in `model.questions` array like `this.model.questions =[{
      key: 'url-links'
    }];`

Comment: Check this out https://ng-run.com/edit/Rs7YIJgJFkfhLht03lp2 If i don't use any async calls it works. Maybe you're filling model.questions too late?

Comment: Filling the model through @Input and recieving in parent component by property binding..